# Activate Bluetooth on a Dell Precision M4600, how to do that?

Tags: bluetooth, dell-precision

I already checked inside the BIOS. There you can control, whether Bluetooth and WLAN belong together when using the hardware switch on the right side of the device. This is the case in my situation. But turning the switch on modifies the LED for WLAN but the LED for bluetooth stays dark. I cannot find a bluetooth driver on Dell's site and the Dell Client System Update works poorly and does not list my bluetooth drivers.

Comment: Is there a bluetooth icon in the taskbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check in the BIOS if your M4600 has bluetooth. It is hard to believe but a phone call to Dell assured us that our model does not have bluetooth installed. It can be detected in the BIOS under "System Information".

Comment: Well, I am having the same problem, I have a new laptop at work and need to use BT with my keyboard. I checked the BIOS and it says that BT is available, but in Windows 7, when I try to install the BT driver from Dell, it stops and asks me to activate BT before installation.

It is driving me mad!

Comment: @FarhadA - did you solve this?  I am having the same unpleasant circular problem!

Answer (score 1):

My Precision M4600 has the same feedback in the BIOS System Information, it has the icon on above the keyboard but apparently there is no driver for it.  It may actually be in the computer but not active somehow.  This is the way alot of nVidia GeForce Cards are, a lot of legacy models were all the same whether you bought a GeForce XXXX but certain features are locked due to the 'model' that was bought but you could unlock them with certain utilities.